# Difference between 'Educational' and 'Education' system

Tags: nouns, adjectives

As a non-native speaker, I'm having difficulties to understand the difference between 'Education system' and 'Educational system'. Is the 'Educational system' appropriate at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Educational** - means something that educates, and it is an adjective
**Education** - is a noun. When used with objects as a determiner it means related to or about education.

In your concrete example **education system** refers to the schools, universities, etc. - the system consisting of different bodies that provide education. Though **educational system** can also be used to refer to the same entity, it is a more general phrase and any system that has an effect of making someone more educated can be considered educational, for example a piece of software that helps kids to learn something can be called **educational system**.

Comment: Educational is often applied to programs and media, such as TV shows, books, etc. An educational show is one that educates. An education show would be a show about education itself.

Answer (score 1):

"Educational System" is a class of system.  An "Education System" is an instance of the class.
"Person" is a class.  "John" is a person.